# Java bot for instagram works different on windows than on ubuntu

Tags: java, request, instagram, bots, limit

I implemented an Instagram bot in java in order to automatically like some photos.
When I run it on my machine (Windows) everything is perfect. When I run it on a VPS (Ubuntu) I get account limit after few likes.
What can be different in these 2 environments and why I am limited on VPS and on my machine not?

Here is the method that creates the request if it helps:

```
private HttpURLConnection prepareRequest(String targetURL, String method,
        String referer) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(targetURL);

        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        request.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        request.setRequestMethod(method);

        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        request.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        if (referer != null) {
            request.setRequestProperty("Referer", referer);
        }

        Cookie csrfCookie = getCookie("csrftoken");
        request.setRequestProperty("X-CSRFToken", csrfCookie.getValue());

        List<Cookie> cookieList = new ArrayList<Cookie>();
        cookieList.add(getCookie("sessionid"));
        cookieList.add(getCookie("mid"));
        cookieList.add(getCookie("csrftoken"));
        cookieList.add(getCookie("urlgen"));

        String cookieHeaderValue = "";
        for (Cookie cookie : cookieList) {
            if (cookie != null) {
                cookieHeaderValue += cookie.getName() + "="
                        + cookie.getValue() + "; ";
            }
        }

        request.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieHeaderValue);
        return request;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log(String.format("Error on preparing the request for %s",
                targetURL));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: It's not an exception. Instagram will temporary restrict my activity and i will not be allowed to do like actions for 1 day. But I don't understand why this is happening only on VPS. What's different there?

Comment: The response for a like in this case will be: feedback_message: "Based on previous use of this feature, your account has been temporarily blocked from taking this action. This block will expire on 2019-03-15."
feedback_title: "Action Blocked"
feedback_url: "repute/report_problem/user_restriction_LIKE_RESTRICT/"
message: "feedback_required"
spam: true
status: "fail"